# Disable youtube autoplay if video has been seen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

Is it possible to disable 'autoplay' of an embedded YouTube video if the visitor's seen it already.

My idea is on front page I've got a video which is set to autoplay, but I don't want it to play every time a visitor returns.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to store which videos the user has seen somewhere, then query that to find which videos should/should not auto play

Comment: it's just one video. any idea how to do that

Comment: You could use a cookie for this.

Comment: Any suggestions on how exactly to achieve it with cookie?